# phpstorm and remote server

Tags: php, ftp, phpstorm, remote-server

I am trying to configure PhpStorm, and I can't seem to find some options that should be there according to their own documentation. I am trying to connect to a remote server with FTP, however, any option regarding deployment, remote servers, remote host are all missing. Is there some setting that must be enabled to have access to them? How could they just be missing?

I am using PhpStorm 6.0.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remote Hosts Access plug-in needs to be enabled:

[image: RHA]

Then you should have Deployment settings where a server can be added:

[image]

Comment: I would not have ever found that. Thanks!

Comment: Is this plugin still available in Intellij IDEA 14.1.4? I can't find it.